# Unity - avoid multiple raycasts on same object to run function multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am using raycast for my weapons to detect if an enemy is hit, and then i run a function to kill the enemy and giving the player a kill while decreasing the enemy count. This works fine for single bullet weapons, but if im using a shotgun which will send out multiple raycast, it will call the function for each bullet hit and therefore the player will get 6 kills if all pellets hit and the enemy count is subtracted by 6.

Below is the function to kill the enemy.

```
public void MonsterDeath()
{

    EnemiesRemaining -= 1;
    Player.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().PlayerGetsKill();
    UIManager.SetEnemiesText(EnemiesRemaining + "");
    if (EnemiesRemaining <= 0)
    {
        WaveOver();
    }

}
```

I tried adding the following code at the top of the function, however it did not make a difference. I'm thinking it might be because it is called in the same frame.

```
if(EnemiesRemaining <= 0)
{
    return;
}
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I am not super experienced with Unity but I'd check the raycast hits before allow your program to make the decision to call MonsterDeath. You can save the colliders in an array and check if it is a monster. Then you check for duplicates and remove them. Then you call the MonsterDeath function on the object. Another thing that comes to mind is to set a boolean that indicates wether the monster has been hit or not.

Comment: I actually did something similar using a list. I will show my solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solve it using a List of GameObject where I added the GameObject of the monsters that recently died.

```
public void MonsterDeath(GameObject monster)
{
    if(DeadMonsters.Contains(monster))
    {
        return;
    }
    DeadMonsters.Add(monster);
    EnemiesRemaining -= 1;
    Player.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().PlayerGetsKill();
    UIManager.SetEnemiesText(EnemiesRemaining + "");
    if (EnemiesRemaining <= 0)
    {
        WaveOver();
    }

}
```

Then at a later time I cleared the list.

```
private void StartWave()
{
    EquipmentSpawner.SpawnEquipment();

    SpawnMonster();
    UIManager.SetEnemiesText(WaveEnemies + "");
    DeadMonsters.Clear();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a component to your monster which has a bool property on it called something like "IsAlive" and only kill the monster if the property is true.

For example

```
public class MonsterComp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsAlive = true;
}
```

And then your earlier code would become

```
public void MonsterDeath(GameObject monster)
{
    MonsterComp monsterComp = monster.GetComponent<MonsterComp>();
    if (monsterComp != null && monsterComp.IsAlive)
    {
        monsterComp.IsAlive = false;
        EnemiesRemaining -= 1;
        Player.GetComponent<PlayerStats>().PlayerGetsKill();
        UIManager.SetEnemiesText(EnemiesRemaining + "");
        if (EnemiesRemaining <= 0)
        {
            WaveOver();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it seemed like it still went through the kill function before IsAlive was set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the monster's collider when it dies.  This way, the next raycast will NOT detect a hit upon it.

```
public void MonsterDeath() //assumes this function is part of the monster's script
{
    GetComponent<Collider>.enabled = false;
    ... existing code....
}
```